# Coordinate transformation from ITRF2008 to ITRF96

Tags: coordinates

I have the following points in units decimal degree and determined in ITRF2008 epoch 2005.0.

```
Latitude(North),Longitude(East),Height,Name
11.124741972222,2.92798011666667,317.16,BJKA
10.253180611111,1.38074808888889,416.96,BJNA
9.9512749611111,3.20403878333333,411.016,BJNI
9.3575081277777,2.62565395,423.923,BJPA
9.3874497833333,2.50852837222222,410.542,BTR1
```

I'd like to show them in ITRF96 epoch 1998.5.

Comment: What have you already tried? Are you using any GIS software, or just needing coordinate conversion?

Comment: Are the heights gravity-related (orthometric, normal, etc.) or ellipsoidal? [EPSG registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) has transformation 6298 but it's using time zero of 2000. Remarks say that the t0 of 2005 differs only in one parameter. To get to 1998.5, you'll need the station velocities, I believe.

Comment: I tried some software get on the web site but I am not sure on the result. Thanks

Comment: I would like to determine them in ITRF96 epoch 1998.5